# Stack Snippet Bug with Tidying CSS

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

This has been a bug for a while and since I haven't seen any reports about it, or comments that a fix was in the works, I thought I'd report it.

Under certain conditions, e.g. having leading blank lines in the CSS code, when tidying a Stack Snippet the formatting becomes worse and extra line breaks are inserted throughout the code. As far as I've seen this only affects the CSS part of Stack Snippets.

The Gif below shows the bug. If the CSS begins on the first line and then you click the tidy button, the code is properly tidied. However if there are leading blank lines and the code is tidied, then you end up with multiple new lines inserted throughout the code.

[image]

The issue is evident on Meta as well. Even one newline before the CSS causes the issue.

Comment: I thought it was meant to be a feature. But it's so annoying.

Comment: Almost certainly a function of the formatting library we use. I think that we could fix it with a trim of whitespace before calling the formatting library. I'll try and take a look this week unless someone on the team beats me to it.

Comment: Actually, it seems like it takes your whitespace as an indication of how many spaces to insert between lines. Might just be configurable. I'll look in a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up - I had not seen it before!

I have fixed the issue by calling `trim()` on the CSS input prior to passing it through to the beautifier method, since it's a third party script and I could not find any configuration options that would fix the issue. It will be live in the next build: (meta: `> rev 2016.6.28.4687`, site: `> rev 2016.6.28.3713`).

Cheers!